# How to sort array by distance from coordinates and model

Tags: arrays, swift, core-location

How I can sort my array by distance after forming it back to model. It is sorted before I filter it back to course format. What I'm doing wrong?

```
class FeedCourseListViewModel: ObservableObject {

  let locationManager = LocationManager.shared
  let courses: [Course]
  var nearestCourses = [Course]()

  init(courses: [Course]) {
    self.courses = courses
    fetchClosestCourses()
  }

  func fetchClosestCourses() {
    if let location = locationManager.location {
      let clLocationArray = courses.map { CLLocation(latitude: $0.location.latitude, longitude: $0.location.longitude) }
      let sortedLocations = clLocationArray.sorted(by: { location.distance(from: $0) < location.distance(from: $1)})
      let prefixedLocations = sortedLocations.prefix(20)
      let nearestLocations = courses.filter { course in
        prefixedLocations.contains { location in
          course.location.latitude == location.coordinate.latitude && course.location.longitude == location.coordinate.longitude
        }
      }
      nearestCourses = nearestLocations
    }
  }
}

struct Course: Identifiable, Decodable {
  let id: String
  let name: String
  let location: Location
}

struct Location: Decodable {
  let latitude: Double
  let longitude: Double
}
```

Comment: `nearestCourses = courses.sorted(by: { aCourse1, aCourse2 in let location1 = CLLocation(latitude: aCourse1.location.latitude, longitude: aCourse1.location.longitude); let location2 = CLLocation(latitude: aCourse2.location.latitude, longitude: aCourse2.location.longitude); return location.distance(from: location1) < location.distance(from: location2) }).prefix(20)` ? Don't map to sort, and refilter later, just sort directly on top level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing:
[Courses] => [CLLocation] => [Sorted - CLLocation] -> [20 first - Sorted - CLLocation]
Filter [Courses] if it's in previous result.

But, you should instead, sort `Courses` directly, and get the 20 first.

```
let sortedCourses = courses.sorted(by: { aCourse1, aCourse2 in 
    let location1 = CLLocation(latitude: aCourse1.location.latitude, longitude: aCourse1.location.longitude) 
    let location2 = CLLocation(latitude: aCourse2.location.latitude, longitude: aCourse2.location.longitude)
    return location.distance(from: location1) < location.distance(from: location2) })

nearestCourses = Array(sortedCourses.prefix(20))
```

Comment: It says when trying convert "nearestCourses" to [Course]: Cannot assign value of type 'Array<Course>.SubSequence' (aka 'ArraySlice<Course>') to type '[Course]'

Comment: Should be fixed now

Comment: why not simply `location.distance(from: $0.location) < location.distance(from: $1.location)` ?

Comment: Because `$0.location` is a `Location`, not a `CLLocation`. I could have add computed properties `asCLLocation` to `Location`, and then maybe `cllocation` to `Course`, but that's might have been going further, when the main logic is still doing the operation on `courses` directly.